# Using a class as a part of another class in django models

Tags: python, django, class, django-models

Assume I am writing an app to change configurations in a machine. I have 3 created tables as below. Machine configuration shows the current state of configurations for our machine. Users can create their tickets and request for changes of the configurations. RequestDetails will be the table to keep the proposed cofigurations plus some extra info such as the name of the requestor, date etc.

These classes are just a simple examples, in the real model I would have nearly 600+ fields=configuration presented in class MachineConfiguration. I should have EXACTLY THE SAME fields in RequestDetails class too. I was wondering there is a way NOT TO REPEAT MYSELF when defining class RequestDetails when it comes to all the fields that exist in MachineConfiguration model?

I want to write it in a way that if I changed anything in MachineConfiguration table, the same change would apply to RequestDetails table too.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
class RequestTicket(models.Model):
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    description=models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)

class MachineConfiguration(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(null=False,blank=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True)
    field_3 = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True)

class RequestDetails(models.Model):
    tracking_number=models.ForeignKey('RequestTicket')
    field_A=models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    field_B=models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)
    field_1 = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True)
    field_3 = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create the base class and inherit that class in another class like,

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And inherit this class in another model to get those same field,

```
# Now if you change any field in BaseModel, it will reflect in both the models
class MachineConfiguration(BaseModel):
    pass

class RequestDetails(BaseModel):
    field3 = models.CharField()
```

Comment: I guess in that case class NewModel will create a table that has ONLY field3 and field1 and field2 will be created in table BaseModel, which is not what I want. I want to create both tables with all the fields in each table. These two tables must be independent of each other. I don't want to have a pointer field in NewModel pointing to field1 and field2

Comment: if abstract=True then django will NOT create a table for the class. This is not what I want. I need to create tables for both classes. See the django documentation for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: That is what i told in answer. Suppose if you want to create 5 models with 3 same fields , inherit this model in those model you want to create db tables

Comment: Like create base_model.py file and in models.py inherit base model in Model MachineConfiguration and RequestDetails

Comment: sounds right, let me check it and I will mark your answer as the right one afterward

Comment: It will gonna work and second models field will change according to first model.